# Catching access to $scope properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

is it possible to catch the following: if I have some template

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    {{notthere}}
</div>
```

and `notthere` is not defined in the controllers `$scope`, can I have a callback fired to handle this? Like:

```
$scope.$catch(function(name) {
    // name === 'notthere'
    return 'someval';
}
```

BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

well, you can do

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
    {{notthere || 'someval'}}
</div>
```

but I'm not sure if this meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I don't thnkg so. Angular (by default) will add `nothere` as a property to link (with the controller's scope) when it is compiling.

You potentially could do something fancy with `preLink` in a directive, but there is no straightforward way to do this.

BTW, the fact that `nothere` is automatically added to the scope can be very beneficial.  It makes it easy to declare "view-only" properties (for validation etc.) that you don't need to concern the controller with.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController",ng-if="nothere!==undefined">
    {{nothere}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="SomeController",ng-if="nothere===undefined">
 someValue
</div>
```